# Navigation Tabs doesn't display the right output

Tags: php, laravel

recently i want to use bootstrap navigation tabs on my laravel project, everyhing went good except the navigation tabs. it display all the result instead per category, and i don't know how the script works on navigation tabs in order to display the result by its category. This is the line of the navigation tabs:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
  <div class="card no-b">
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
          <div class="align-self-center">
              <strong>Live Streaming</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="align-self-end float-right">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs nav-material" role="tablist">
                @foreach($radiocategory as $rc)
                @if($loop->first)
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active show" id="{{ $rc->category_name }}" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ $rc->category_name }}"
                       role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true">{{ $rc->category_name }}</a>
                </li>
                @else
                <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link show" id="{{ $rc->category_name }}" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ $rc->category_name }}"
                           role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true">{{ $rc->category_name }}</a>
                    </li>
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body no-p">
        <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent1">
            @foreach($radio as $r)
            @if($loop->first)
            <div class="tab-pane fade show" id="{{ $r->category }}" role="tabpanel"
            aria-labelledby="{{ $r->category }}">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover earning-box">

                        <tbody>
                        <tr class="no-b">
                            <td class="w-10"><span class="round">
                        <img src="/img/{{ $r->image }}" alt="{{ $r->title }}"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <h6>{{ $r->title }}</h6>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <div class="ml-auto">
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{{ $r->url }}">Listen Now</a>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            @else
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="{{ $r->category }}" role="tabpanel"
                    aria-labelledby="{{ $r->category }}">
                 <div class="table-responsive">
                   <table class="table table-hover earning-box">

                     <tbody>
                     <tr class="no-b">
                         <td class="w-10"><span class="round">
                     <img src="/img/{{ $r->image }}" alt="{{ $r->title }}"></span>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                             <h6>{{ $r->title }}</h6>
                         </td>
                         <td>
                         <div class="ml-auto">
                         <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{{ $r->url }}">Listen Now</a>
                         </div>
                         </td>
                     </tr>
                     </tbody>
                   </table>
                 </div>
               </div>
            @endif
            @endforeach
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is my controller :

```
public function home() {
      $music = Music::orderByRaw('RAND()')->get();
      $posts = Posts::orderByRaw('RAND()')->take(4)->get();
      $radio = DB::table('radio')
                 ->join('radio_category', 'radio.category', '=', 'radio_category.category_name')
                 ->select('radio.*')
                 ->get();

      $radiocategory = RadioCategory::all();
      return view('index',
                   ['music' => $music,
                    'posts' => $posts,
                    'radio' => $radio,
                    'radiocategory' => $radiocategory
                ]);
    }
```

The output was :
[it should be the result that are inside a HardRock category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCSct.png)
What's wrong in my code ?

Comment: I think `<div class="tab-pane fade show" id="{{ $r->category }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="{{ $r->category }}">` should be `<div class="tab-pane fade show" id="{{ $r->category->name }}" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="{{ $r->category->name }}">`

Answer (score 0):

In your view you are displaying all radiocategories (`$radiocategory = RadioCategory::all();`):

```
@foreach($radiocategory as $rc)
    @if($loop->first)
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active show" id="{{ $rc->category_name }}" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ $rc->category_name }}"
                   role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true">{{ $rc->category_name }}</a>
        </li>
    @else
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link show" id="{{ $rc->category_name }}" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ $rc->category_name }}"
                       role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true">{{ $rc->category_name }}</a>
        </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Instead call categories which belong to radio:

```
@foreach($radio->category as $rc)
    @if($loop->first)
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active show" id="{{ $rc->category_name }}" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ $rc->category_name }}"
                   role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true">{{ $rc->category_name }}</a>
        </li>
    @else
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link show" id="{{ $rc->category_name }}" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{ $rc->category_name }}"
                       role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-expanded="true" aria-selected="true">{{ $rc->category_name }}</a>
        </li>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Where `$radio->category` is the relation of radio with the category in radio model.